# awk to parse input with multiple conditions

Tags: awk

This post in a continuation of:

using `awk` to parse specific condition and apologize if I should have added to the thread, should I have added it to that post?  I have tried to modify the below `awk` script, but with no luck

```
awk 'NR==2 {
  split($2,a,"[_.>]");b=substr(a[4],1,length(a[4]-1));
  print a[2]+0,b,b,substr(a[4],length(a[4])),a[5]}' \
OFS="\t" ${id}_position.txt > ${id}_parse.txt
```

I have multiple possible condition that a user could input resulting in different output.  One of those conditions is in the data sample, with the field in bold needed to be parsed:

```
` parse rules:
1. 4 zeros after the NC_  (not always the case) and the digits before the .
2. g. ### (before underscore)  _### (# after the _)
3. TG (letters after del)
4. -  (hyphen used in this spot)`
```

Data Sample

```
 Input Variant  Errors  Chromosomal Variant Coding Variant(s)
 NM_004004.5:c.575_576delCA     **NC_000013.10:g.20763145_20763146delTG** NM_004004.5:c.575_576delCA    XM_005266354.1:c.575_576delCA XM_005266355.1:c.575_576delCA XM_005266356.1:c.575_576delCA
```

Desired Output

```
13     20763145     20763146     TG     -
```

Thank you :).

Comment: your current code only works on the 2nd record read. Is that as you intend? If you're trying to skip a header record, and then process everything after that, you'll want `NR>1`. And, sorry to say, but as is, this question is high on the incomprehensible scale. You say " I have multiple possible conditions", but then the next sentence is "One of this conditions is ...". Well so are you only interested in solving that one case? If so, the "multiple possible conditions" doesn't help our understanding. Until you understand awk better, I'd recommend solving one problem at a time. Good luck.

Comment: Maybe rather than have these obfuscating strings (your data sample), post I have `NC_000013.10:g.20763145_20763146delTG` and I need to extract just the `13` from the leftmost `NC_000013`. Get all of those translations working, then we can add logic to process or skip records as needed. Put another way, simple examples of sample input and the required output, along with your attempt to solve, your current output and exact text of any error messages, make it easier to help.  Good luck.

Comment: I don't really understand the question but you can use match in awk to pull out strings. For example the NC string awk 'match($0,/NC_0000(..)\./,NC){print NC[0]}' would print 13. Change and repeat as needed :)

Comment: Yes, I am intending on on skipping the header and the posted code works great for one condition or data format.  However, if that format is different, as posted, then the `awk` does not work.  I am trying to redo the code to get it work on condition 1 (already working) and also on condition 2.  Thank you :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TXR Language:

```
Input Variant@(skip)
@(skip)NC_@{nc-raw}.@(skip)g.@{g-left}_@{g-right}del@{letters 2}@(skip)
@(bind nc-num @(int-str nc-raw))
@(output)
@{nc-num 6} @{g-left 12} @{g-right 12} @{letters 6} -
@(end)
```

Run:

```
$ txr nc.txr data
13     20763145     20763146     TG     -
```

All in the command line:

```
$ txr -c 'Input Variant@(skip)
@(skip)NC_@{nc-raw}.@(skip)g.@{g-left}_@{g-right}del@{letters 2}@(skip)
@(bind nc-num @(int-str nc-raw))
@(output)
@{nc-num 6} @{g-left 12} @{g-right 12} @{letters 6} -
@(end)' data
13     20763145     20763146     TG     -
```